# PHP - How to edit Array Elements from JSON File?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm learning more about parsing JSON in PHP, and I encountered a problem editing a certain file.

I wrote a code that makes it possible to edit only the values I want from a JSON file, and for some reason, when I try to edit the value from "IdList", my code replaces that value without the square brackets, invalidating the JSON structure.

How could I get my code to correctly override this value while keeping it inside the square bracket?

My JSON File

```
{
"isVisible": false,
"Name": "Lorem ipslum",
"Int": 0,
"IdList": [10, 30, 70],
"UseKeys": true,
}
```

My PHP code

```
<?php

$commandline = ($_GET[("string")]);
$json_object = file_get_contents('file.json');

$data = json_decode($json_object, true);
$data['IdList'] = $commandline;
$json_object = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
file_put_contents('file.json', $json_object);
echo('success');
?>
```

When i try to change IdList to '70, 80, 90' for example, the Json file is saved like this:

```
"IdList":"70, 80, 90"
```

It should be saving like this:

```
"IdList": [70, 80, 90]
```

When I try to modify the text from the other values, it works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting a `string` for `"IdList"`

this would work for you:

```
$data['IdList'] = array_map('intval', explode(',',$commandline));
```

Comment: Works great for the problem I was having. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this line:

```
$data['IdList'] = $commandline;
```

With:

```
$data['IdList'] = json_decode('[' . $commandline . ']', true);
```

Comment: Your solution was helpful and I will definitely use it soon for other scenarios. Thanks a lot for your contribution :)